# Reversing a number using recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I was tasked with reversing an integer recursively. I have an idea of how to formulate my base case but I'm unsure of what to put outside of the if statement. The parts I was unsure about are commented with question marks. With the first part, I don't know what to put and with the second part I'm unsure about whether it is correct or not.Thank you for the help.

Note: I'd like to avoid using external functions such as imports and things like these if possible.

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
    if number < 10:
        return number
    return # ??????????
def main():
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print(number,end="") #???????????
    reverseDisplay(number)

main()
```

Comment: If I have the base 10 number '123456' then its reverse is '6' concatenated with the reverse of '12345'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the answer, but I'll give some hints. It looks like you don't want to convert it to a string -- this makes it a more interesting problem, but will result in some funky behavior. For example, `reverseDisplay(100) = 1`.

However, if you don't yet have a good handle on recursion, I would strongly recommend that you convert the input to a string and try to recursively reverse that string. Once you understand how to do that, an arithmetic approach will be much more straightforward.

Your base case is solid. A digit reversed is that same digit.

```
def reverseDisplay(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    last_digit = # ??? 12345 -> 4
    other_digits = # ??? You'll use last_digit for this. 12345 -> 1234
    return last_digit * 10 ** ??? + reverseDisplay(???)
    # ** is the exponent operator. If the last digit is 5, this is going to be 500...
    # how many zeroes do we want? why?
```

If you don't want to use any string operations whatsoever, you might have to write your own function for getting the number of digits in an integer. Why? Where will you use it?

---

Imagine that you have a string 12345.

```
reverseDisplay(12345) is really 
    5 + reverseDisplay(1234) ->
        4 + reverseDisplay(123) ->
            3 + reverseDisplay(12) ->
                2 + reverseDisplay(1) ->
                    1
```

Comment: So I should be separating the original input into new variables?

Comment: @user3495234 variables aren't the important concept here, but I think you have the right idea. We need the last part of the number to go first, and the rest to be fed back into the function. It doesn't matter whether we store them as variables in between, I just did that for readability.

Comment: Is there a way to do it while still retaining the print(,end="") function I had? I feel like there should be an easier way using that which would negate the use of exponents.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it might be a terrible idea, but who knows may be it will help:

1. Convert it to string.
2. Reverse the string using the recursion. Basically take char from the back, append to the front.
3. Parse it again.

Not the best performing solution, but a solution...

Otherwise there is gotta be some formula. For instance here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323268/formula-to-reverse-digits

Comment: I was aware of that possibility but I'd like to try avoiding that if possible. Otherwise I'll never really learn recursion.

Comment: @user3495234 This is still "recursion" and is a perfectly valid way to do it. If you would rather not ever convert it to a string, think for a minute about what mathematical operations you would need to perform to do the equivalent thing.

Comment: @user3495234 I have an answer for you that includes just math. But it's too late to type it now. Will do tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of digits, that you want to turn into an `int`:

```
[1,2,3,4] -> 1234
```

You do this by 1*10^3 + 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 4.*10^0. The powers of 10 are exactly reversed in the case that you want to reverse the number. This is done as follows:

```
def reverse(n):
    if n<10:
        return n
    return (n%10)*10**(int(math.log(n,10))) + reverse(n//10)
```

That `math.log` stuff simply determines the number of digits in the number, and therefore the power of 10 that should be multiplied.

Output:

```
In [78]: reverse(1234)
Out[78]: 4321

In [79]: reverse(123)
Out[79]: 321

In [80]: reverse(12)
Out[80]: 21

In [81]: reverse(1)
Out[81]: 1

In [82]: reverse(0)
Out[82]: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Does exactly what @GregS suggested in his comment. Key to reverse is to extract the last digit using the modulos operator and convert each extracted digit to a string, then simply join them back into the reverse of the string:

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
    if number < 10:
        return str(number)
    return str(number % 10) + reverseDisplay(number / 10)

def main():
    print (reverseDisplay(int(input("Enter a number: "))))

main()
```

Alternative method without using recursion:

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
    return str(number)[::-1]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without converting to string?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but if you have the number `19000`, you will not get `00091` using that method. I will post the method as well

Comment: @user3495234, on second thought, I can't think of a way of doing it without resolving to log or math library like inspectorG4dget did